# How to extend GenericPathRoutecs of NopCommerce CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Is there a way to extend the supported entities in the GenericPathRoute.cs GetRouteData(...) from my custom plugin so that I can add generic url support for my custom entity?

```
//process URL
            switch (urlRecord.EntityName.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "product":
                    {
                        data.Values["controller"] = "Catalog";
                        data.Values["action"] = "Product";
                        data.Values["productid"] = urlRecord.EntityId;
                        data.Values["SeName"] = urlRecord.Slug;
                    }
                    break;
                 ...
                case "MyCustomEntity":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May try this :

```
 <i>
 public class CmsCustomUrlRecordEntityNameRequested : IConsumer<CustomUrlRecordEntityNameRequested>
{

    void HandleEvent(CustomUrlRecordEntityNameRequested eventMessage)
    {
                            eventMessage.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Topic";
                            eventMessage.RouteData.Values["action"] = "TopicDetails";
                            eventMessage.RouteData.Values["topicId"] = urlRecord.EntityId;
                            eventMessage.RouteData.Values["SeName"] = urlRecord.Slug;
    }

}

</i>
```

Comment: you handle this event : EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IEventPublisher>()
                                .Publish(new CustomUrlRecordEntityNameRequested(data, urlRecord));